# decoding 16 bit int value stored in RGB565 texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, bit-manipulation, shader, hlsl

I am trying to use Unity and the Xbox Kinect to create a game/prototype.

The depth camera on the kinect returns a byte[] of 16bit uint values.
I am currently creating a Unity Texture2D object and specifying the format as RGB565 then populating it using the LoadRawTextureData function. This works fine and within the Unity environment I can see at runtime the texture being made and updating.

However, when I sample the texture in the shader I am really not sure of how to decode the encoded value back to the original depth int. I have tried a number of things but unfortunately no luck, I was hoping someone would be able to point me in the right direction.

```
        float decodeFloatRGB565(float4 enc) {
             //... decode value ...     
        }

        // The vertex shader - handles the position of the vertex 
        v2f vert(appdata v) {
            v2f o;
            o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
            o.uv = v.uv;

            float4 depthRGBA = tex2Dlod(_DepthTex, float4(v.uv,0.0,0.0));
            float val = decodeFloatRGB565(depthRGBA);

            //...scale to value between 0 and 255...
            //...scale to value between 0 and 1...

            o.color = float4(val,val,val,0.0);

            return o;
        }

        // The fragment shader - handles the color of vertex
        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target { 
            return i.color; 
        }
```

Any help massively appreciated.

Comment: Is the R16 texture format not supported on your platform?

Comment: I believe it is - I did actually try that first as I assumed it would be easier. As  I understand that would be 16 bits all in the red channel? When I then applied the sampler to the texture there only seemed to be data in the alpha channel - I must have been doing something weird I guess.

Comment: Dont `Sample` (or `tex2D`) the encoded value unless you're doing nearest-neighbor sampling. The interpolated value is meaningless.

Comment: @MooseBoys What else can be used to get the value of a pixel from a texture in a shader program than tex2D?

Comment: @Tylo in SM4+ there are `Load` and `Gather` which take integer coordinates and no sampler. But I'm not sure if this is available in SM2/DX9.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if HLSL and your target platform support bitwise operators ([seems to be true](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509631(v=vs.85).aspx)), but if there're here's a possible solution:

```
uint depth = (uint) enc.r * 31 << 11 | 
             (uint) enc.g * 63 << 5 |
             (uint) enc.b * 31;
```